# Ratio of two triangles.

Tags: geometry

In the triangle ABC, the point P lies in the third of the segment AB near point A, the point R is in the third segment PB near the point P, and the point Q lies on the cutting line BC so that the angles PCB and RQB are equal. Determine the ratio of ABC and PQC triangle.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: You should probably share your attempts.

Comment: I know that point Q lies on a third of the line BC, near point C.

Comment: Ok, then $\triangle PCB \sim \triangle QRB$ with known ratio. Use also the fact that ratio between the areas of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PCB$ is known.

Comment: I don't know the ratio.

Comment: The similarity ratio between $\triangle PCB$ and triangle $\triangle QRB$ is $\frac32$. The ratio between the *areas* of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PCB$ is $\frac32$ (why?).

Comment: Could u explain it more bit?

Comment: Triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PCB$ share the altitude with respect to $AB$ and their respective bases have ratio $\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{PB}}=\frac32$

Comment: But I don't still know how to deduce the ratio between ABC and PCB by their area is 2/3.

Comment: That is precisely the consequence of my previous comment. You got two triangles with same altitude and base with ratio $\frac32$...

Comment: Oh, it didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Comment: Use the same approach for $\triangle PQC$ and $\triangle PBC$ and you are done.

Comment: So the area of PCB would be 2/3 of ABC and the area of the PQC would be 4/9 of the area of ABC. Thank you for support.

Comment: I also suggest you post the answer yourself once you are done!